# Is it possible to find all U.S. federal laws digitized and online?

Tags: united-states, public-domain, us-federal-government

Are all of the **federal laws** in the United States digitized and available to the public through some free ".gov" website? Is it possible to download them all into, say, PDF?

Comment: [Office of Federal Register](https://www.archives.gov/federal-register/laws), although I'm not sure of an easy way to download them all in any specific format. Some laws are pretty big, so it is a lot of data you would be requesting. There is a [bulk data link](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/bulkdata), a lot of what you may be after would probably be in the "Code of Federal Regulations".

Comment: Thanks @RonBeyer (+1) - just curious though: what's the difference between the content thats available at the Office of Federal Register vs Library of Congress (LOC)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://uscode.house.gov/download/download.shtml to start.

But what exactly do you mean by a "law"? Lots falls under that term: do you include case law? SCOTUS decisions? Administrative policies? Read earlier Law SE question [Naive approach to aggregating all US Federal Laws?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/24532/naive-approach-to-aggregating-all-us-federal-laws)

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [Cornell University's Legal Information Institute](https://www.law.cornell.edu/).

They have the US Constitution, the US Code, the Code of Federal Regulations, Supreme Court decisions, state laws, international law resources, and more, conveniently accessible from a single page.